# How are BRR weights used in the survey package for R?

Tags: r, survey, replicate

Does anyone know how to use BRR weights in Lumley's survey package for estimating variance if your dataset *already* has BRR weights it in?

I am working with PISA data, and they already include 80 BRR replicates in their dataset. How can I get as.svrepdesign to use these, instead of trying to create its own? I tried the following and got the subsequent error:

```
dstrat <- svydesign(id=~uniqueID,strata=~strataVar, weights=~studentWeight, 
                data=data, nest=TRUE)
dstrat <- as.svrepdesign(dstrat, type="BRR")

Error in brrweights(design$strata[, 1], design$cluster[, 1], ..., 
    fay.rho = fay.rho,  : Can't split with odd numbers of PSUs in a stratum
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: to work with pisa in R, [this](http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/program%20for%20international%20student%20assessment%20%28pisa%29) will do the correct setup for you :)  you'll need to incorporate the multiple imputation in your analysis, which those scripts automate.

Comment: You could also try the `RALSA` package which has a graphical user interface: https://cran.r-project.org/package=RALSA For guides on how to use it, see here: http://ralsa.ineri.org/user-guide/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no need to use `as.svrepdesign()` if you have a data frame with the replicate weights already :)  you can create the replicate weighted design directly from your data frame.

say you have data with a main weight column called `mainwgt` and 80 replicate weight columns called `repwgt1` through `repwgt80` you could use this --

```
yoursurvey <-
    svrepdesign( 
    weights = ~mainwgt , 
    repweights = "repwgt[0-9]+" , 
    type = "BRR", 
    data = yourdata ,
    combined.weights = TRUE
)
```

-- this way, you don't have to identify the exact column numbers.  then you can run normal survey commands like --

```
svymean( ~variable , design = yoursurvey )
```

if you'd like another example, here's [some example code](https://github.com/ajdamico/usgsd/blob/9be971706a69f4e569a7d5643eab602a5c27b311/Current%20Population%20Survey/replicate%20census%20estimates%20-%202011.R#L81) and [an explanatory blog post](http://usgsd.blogspot.com/search/label/current%20population%20survey%20%28cps%29) using the current population survey.

Comment: is it not necessary to specify `type` and `rho` arguments? I suppose one needs to know the specific design of the replicate weights to know?

Comment: i think type defaults to "BRR" but not 100%.  rho is only needed for type = "Fay" [example](https://github.com/ajdamico/usgsd/blob/9be971706a69f4e569a7d5643eab602a5c27b311/Current%20Population%20Survey/2012%20asec%20-%20analysis%20examples.R#L80). :)

Comment: this answer is not sufficient if you use any of the "plausible values" variables (which are probably central to any analysis).  to use those correctly, use [this setup instead](http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/program%20for%20international%20student%20assessment%20%28pisa%29).

Comment: @AnthonyDamico would you please have a look at this link to provide ur suggestion for my question there please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77490683/convert-the-sas-proc-surveyfreq-into-r-language-create-stat-for-survey-data-wit

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used the PISA data, I used the `svprepdesign` method last year with the Public Use Microsample from the American Community Survey (US Census Bureau) which also shipped with 80 replicate weights. They state to use the `Fay` method for that specific survey, so here is how one can construct the `svyrep` object using that data:

```
pums_p.rep<-svrepdesign(variables=pums_p[,2:7],
    repweights=pums_p[8:87],
    weights=pums_p[,1],combined.weights=TRUE,
    type="Fay",rho=(1-1/sqrt(4)),scale=1,rscales=1)

attach(pums_p.rep)
#CROSS - TABS
#unweighted
xtabs(~ is5to17youth + withinAMILimit) 
table(is5to17youth + withinAMILimit)

#weighted, mean income by sex by race for select age groups
svyby(~PINCP,~RAC1P+SEX,subset(
   pums_p.rep,AGEP > 25 & AGEP <35),na.rm = TRUE,svymean,vartype="se","cv")
```

In getting this to work, I found the [article](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2009-2/RJournal_2009-2_Damico.pdf) from A. Damico helpful: `Damico, A. (2009). Transitioning to R: Replicating SAS, Stata, and SUDAAN Analysis Techniques in Health Policy Data. The R Journal, 1(2), 37–44.`

Comment: ako would you please have a look at this link to provide ur suggestion for my question there please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77490683/convert-the-sas-proc-surveyfreq-into-r-language-create-stat-for-survey-data-wit